# Cannot connect on open port

Tags: iptables, tomcat, jira

I just installed Jira with embedded Tomcat, which runs on port 8080.
I gave `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` and `netstat -tpln` says:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      645/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29336/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13598/postgres      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1101/master                 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      645/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      13598/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1101/master         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      27788/java
tcp6        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29336/java
```

Locally, it works. From remote it doesn't. What should I checkout to get a better insight on the problem?

PS I've also followed this to save iptables changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756240/how-can-i-use-iptables-on-centos-7

PPS I executed the previous commands also with ip6tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was enough to be more precise with the command, like this: `iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

It seems, Tomcat listens on IPv6 only.
May be you missed something during installation?

Check this link for further information: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+run+JIRA+on+a+specific+IP

Comment: That's weird. I followed the default values. I made the switch to ipv4 following this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/320131/change-localhost-for-confluence

Answer (score 0):

> What shouldI checkout?

This

> `tcp6     0      0 :::8080         :::*             LISTEN      27788/java`

It looks like your Jira process is listening on an IPv6 TCP port and not an IPv4 TCP port. You have only opened a port on your IPv4 firewall, you will need to open the same port in your IPv6 firewall - see [ip6tables(1)](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ip6tables.man.html).

On CentOS 7 there is also firewalld which may offer a better solution.

Comment: I omitted that part, sorry. Of course I gave the same commands on ip6tables.

Comment: OP updated to avoid confusion

Comment: Are you connecting via IPv6 externally ?

Comment: Nope, no way I can. I moved it to ipv4, though, so we can proceed on that.

Comment: I decline. This is a Q&A site not Remote Diagnostics as a Service.